# newly loaded javascript file is not working in phantomjs

Tags: javascript, php, phantomjs

I have created one js file which is having some variables and constants.
for ex :

```
first.js 
var a = 10;
b = 15;
```

I need to include this file in my `phantomjs` file and use these varaibles.

My phantom js code is like this

```
   page.onLoadFinished = function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            var my_var = run_stats();
            page.close();
            system.stdout.writeLine(JSON.stringify(my_var));
            phantom.exit(0);
        },2000);
    };

    page.open(phantom.args[0],function(status){
        system.stderr.writeLine(status);
        if(status !== 'success'){
            console.log('unable to open the page '+phantom.args[0]);
            phantom.exit(0);
        }
    });

function run_stats(){
   page.injectJs('jquery-1.9.1.min.js');
   page.injectJs('first.js');

    my_var = page.evaluate(function() {
        console.log(a); //here the variables are working
        console.log(a); 
    }
    console.log(a); //here, not working
}
```

what should I do to use my variables outside the evaluate function.

I am explaining you very briefly. Please try to understand my problem and help me to resolve it.

Comment: you are calling `'first.js'` using `page` so its work inside `page.evaluate` because the `first.js` is readable by `page` try to define `var aa;` above `my_var = page.evaluate` then set the value `aa = a` inside `page.evaluate` , below `page.evaluate` add `console.log(aa);` this should work

Comment: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object` is getting when i `console.log(aa)`;

Comment: i have posted my answer to make it more clearly to you, have you tried it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried that

```
var aa ;
function run_stats(){
   page.injectJs('jquery-1.9.1.min.js');
   page.injectJs('first.js');

    my_var = page.evaluate(function() {
        console.log(a); //here the variables are working
        console.log(a); 
         aa = a;
    }
    console.log(aa); //here, not working
}
```

Comment: Your answer is very clear.. but, I am getting `undefined` for the value `aa`

Comment: wired try to define a to page for example page.a = a; inside `my_var = page.evaluate(function() {` then `console.log(page.a); ` its a trick